# How to list autocomplete results as a link?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I am new on Ajax. I need to find how to list autocomplete results as a link. When user clicks the result should open that link. I can list the related result but I couldn't find how to add the links. It should be added somewhere in the script as a html tag. Please give me some clue how to add html link

Here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        SearchText();
    });
    function SearchText() {
        $(".auto").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "Default.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                    data: "{'question':'" + document.getElementById('txtQuestion').value + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data.d);
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("Error Occurred");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Here is the method which connects to the db and returns related results:

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<string> GetAutoCompleteData(string question)
{
    List<string> result = new List<string>();
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx+"))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Questions,Link FROM DigiQA WHERE Questions LIKE '%'+@quest+'%'", conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quest", question);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                result.Add(dr["Questions"].ToString());
            }
            return result;
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
success: function(data) {
    response($jQuery.map(data, function(item) {
        return {
           label: '<a href="yoururl">' + item + '</a>'),
           value: item
        }
    }))
}
```

Comment: Can I prepare this result by code? Like this: 
result.Add("<a href=\"" + dr["Link"].ToString() +  "\">" + dr["Questions"].ToString() + "</a>");